# How to completly mute unbuffered live NetStream in Flash AS3/haxe?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, haxe

I have a live NetStream created and used as follows:

```
m_stream = new NetStream(m_connection);
m_stream.bufferTime = 0;

// mutes most of the sounds in exchange of clicking noise
m_stream.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0); 
m_stream.receiveAudio(false); // seems to have no effect at all on rtmp streams

m_video.attachNetStream(m_stream);
m_stream.play(m_chan,-1,-1,true);
```

The problem is that despite SoundTransform with zero volume level applied, i still sometime hear "clicking" noise when actual sound is happening on the muted stream. There is no such problem on buffered streams, only on unbuffered (`m_stream.bufferTime = 0`); but i don't want to increase buffering time because 1) i want as less latency as possible and 2) even very short buffer (like for 1.0 seconds) will delay the video for more than 10-20 seconds eventually.

Is there a way to mute all sounds completly? I have been trying to do something like

```
SoundMixer.stopAll();
SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
```

but that didn't spared me of clicking sounds as well.

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to solve the click issue back then? I have same problem but using appendbytes (and if the `ns.bufferLength` tracing reaches "0" then that subtle clicking starts)... Any hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong. I've done it before and receiveAudio(false) worked as it was supposed to do. Also, the sounds you hear are probably the result of having a bad internet connection.

Comment: I mean, try again and make sure this is the actual code it runs, because it seems like `m_stream.receiveAudio(false);` is not executed. Also, post the full code with the event cycle.